# How to deploy .Net project using Bamboo?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, bamboo, continuous-deployment

I am new to bamboo CI, I need help in Continuous Deployment of MVC5 .Net project in Bamboo.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-net-and-bamboo-289277288.html